# Align array of objects and merge with latest

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, merge, sequence

I have an original array that I need to merge with second updated array and capture the actions performed.

to simplify I have this sequence. the sequence in array is always ordered by property `order`. however this is not constantly bound to the position.

```
//length can vary
let initial = [
{pos: 'a', order: '1'},
{pos: 'c', order: '2'},
{pos: 'g', order: '3'},
{pos: 't', order: '4'}, 
{pos: 'q'},
{pos: 'r'}, 
{pos: 'c'}, 
{pos: 'g'}, 
{pos: 'p'},
{pos: 'c'}, 
{pos: 'g'}, 
{pos: 't'}]

//length can vary to initial sequence
let updated = [
{pos: 'a', order: '1'} 
{pos: 'p', order: '2'}, 
{pos: 'm', order: '3'}, 
{pos: 'g', order: '4'}, 
{pos: 't', order: '5'}, // NB: order has changed for `pos: t`. however it's still ordered within array.
{pos: 'q'}, 
{pos: 'r'}, 
{pos: 'c'}, 
{pos: 'g'}, 
{pos: 'p'}, 
{pos: 'c'}, 
{pos: 't'}]
```

I need to capture the change so that

```
let reconciled = [
{pos: 'a'}, 
{pos: 'c', action: 'removed', order: '2'}, // Order # is irrelevant for delete. array position matters.
{pos: 'p', action: 'insert', order: '2'}, 
{pos: 'm', action: 'insert' order: '3'}, 
{pos: 'g'}, 
{pos: 't'}, 
{pos: 'q'}, 
{pos: 'r'}, 
{pos: 'c'}, 
{pos: 'g'},
{pos: 'p'}, 
{pos: 'c'}, 
{pos: 'g': action: 'removed'}, 
{pos: 't'}]

// or

let reconciled = [
{pos: 'a', order: '1'}, 
{pos: 'p', action: 'insert', order: '2'}, 
{pos: 'm', action: 'insert' order: '3'}, 
{pos: 'c', action: 'removed', order: '2'}, // Order # is irrelevant for delete. array position matters.
{pos: 'g'}, // no action
{pos: 't'}, // no action
{pos: 'q'}, // no action
{pos: 'r'}, // no action
{pos: 'c'}, // no action
{pos: 'g'}, // no action
{pos: 'p'}, // no action
{pos: 'c'}, // no action
{pos: 'g': action: 'removed'}, 
{pos: 't'}] // no action performed here
```

I've tried with `union`, `intersection`, `xor`, `merge`, `new Set()`, `new Map()` etc etc. However the solutions I have doesn't account for duplicates and removes the duplicates. 
e.g. in initial Array `pos: 'c'` occurs at index `1`, `6` and `9` each of these are unique 
so in the updated array it should register `pos: 'c'` as removed from index `1`, while at index `8` and `11` (in the updated array) remains the same.

Notice at index `1-3` in updated array captures the insertion and deletions. Because `c` was removed and `p` and `m` were spliced in to the position. So whether `c` appears before or after the spliced items are irrelevant but should appear together.

Also notice how other elements in array hasn't changed i.e. not inserted or deleted from the sequence.

Comment: What does "capture the actions performed" mean? Because it sounds like you're trying to find a diff, in which case something like https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch is probably easier than rolling your own solution?

Comment: check in the updated array whether object is removed, or new object is inserted in to array.

Comment: then yeah, see first comment.